# Use splats with eval()

Tags: python

So, I am fully aware of how *evil* `eval()` is, but how would I use a splat with it? Say I have a string that says `"func(arg1, arg2)"` I then separate it into `["func", "arg1", "arg2"]`. How would I use `eval()` to use a splat in order to run every argument given into the function.

Example:

```
funcs = ("saySomething", "yellTaco")
def saySomething(something):
 print(something)
def yellTaco(times):
 for i in range(times):
  print("TACO")
c = input("> ") # Let's say I input: "saySomething your-mom"
c = c.split(" ")
if c[0] in funcs:
 eval(c[0]+"("+[HOW DO I PUT A SPLAT FOR THE REST OF THE TABLE HERE?]+")")
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn them into a comma-separated string.

```
', '.join(c[1:])
```

Comment: Arrrgh! That was so simple, surprised I didn't think of that. Thank you!